# Why .htaccess blocks access to a .php file

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

I have a .htaccess file in my web server that removes index.php from my URL's.
The problem comes when I want to access a .php file located in a subdirectory of my webserver.

My htacess file is like this:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting

RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory

RewriteBase /


# Protect application and system files from being viewed

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]


# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

And now if I wanted to access a .php file like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder/assets/17041f49/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php

The server returned an 500 error.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Look in the server error logs. It will tell you what part of the the .htaccess it doesn't like.

Comment: There is *most likely* an error in the `tiny_mce_gzip.php` file that is causing the problem - if you remove the `.htaccess` file, do you still get the error?

Comment: I fixed it now, by changing the file permission for http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder/assets/17041f49 to 555. Everything works now. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, even after removing .htaccess from the webserver, it still returns a 500 error.
If I change the tiny_mce_gzip.php to contain only echo 'a', it still doesn't work.

Comment: WEll what where the permissions before you changed them to 555 (And that is kinda odd, one would normally want 755 on the directory to allow owner to write to it as well. Again the error logs will tell you what the actual issue is..

Comment: I got it, the file permission of tiny_mce_gzip.php is 644, but the folder containing it has a permission of 777. 
So the php script could not be executed.
Why is this so? assets is a folder that is automatically created by a library from my php framework, so I couldn't change it's permission directly.

The error log in my webserver says:
[Mon May 02 20:58:01 2011] [error] [client 175.106.13.5] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/k7015299/public_html/adaru/assets/17041f49" is writeable by group.

Comment: my guess is that it is running under suphp / suexec that will prohibit scripts from running if they are group/other writeable, as it is a security issue.  You should be able to adjust the umask that the program uses to create files, that will fix those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).(css|js|xml|ico|png|gif|jpe?g)$ $1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Then get the requested URL in PHP usig

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```